# Firestore cache not sync

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore on typescript, with cache enabled (`enablePersistence`)

The issue is when i'm deleting some products in firestore, when I get from firestore (through the admin interface, or by an other instance of the app), it's seems that's the products are returned from the cache (and then the delete is not sync with cache)

```
async getProductList(): Promise<Product[]> {
        const collection = this.db.collection(`products`)
        const snapshot = await collection.get();

        return snapshot.docs.map((doc: any) => {
            console.log(doc.data())
            return doc.data()
        });
}
```

See the firestore emulator (only 1 product, I deleted product with id `5656`)

[image]

But in my console on the app, I get 2 products (with deleted one) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was using firestore emulator

```
   firebase.firestore().settings({
        host: "localhost:8080",
        ssl: false,
        experimentalForceLongPolling: true 
    });
```

And this was the issue. When I use the real firestore env, I don't have the problem anymore. Strange !